# Cannot load project .Net

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

I can't upload an project.
Error message is :

> .\..\..\...\TestManager.xproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I tried to install .Net Core SDK 1.0.1 but nothing change.

Comment: The triple dot after the third backslash maybe the problem - it is not a valid path in Windows (single dot is current folder, double dot parent)

Comment: Check the path.  My projects never end up in Program Files(x86),

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a project.json based .net core project, make sure that the .net core tools preview has been installed on the machine you build on and a global.json file contains an SDK version definition for a project.json based CLI version. See [this document](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/8bd15c7ec03a23a8666b5f5ab6d3d89baf192acd/Documentation/ProjectJsonToCSProj.md#how-do-i-work-with-projectjson-and-csproj-on-the-same-machine) that explains how to keep project.json projects working.

However, since the preview tooling is no longer supported, you should consider switching to VS 2017 and `.csproj` based tooling that the `1.0.0`+ versions of the .net CLI support. See [this documentation for migrating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migration/).